# What is exactly given to Meteor.methods() function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Take a look at this sample code:

```
Meteor.methods({
'tasks.insert'(text) {
    check(text, String);

    // and other stuff...
},
'tasks.remove'(taskId) {
    check(taskId, String);
    Tasks.remove(taskId);
},
});
```

methods() function tooks js object literal, but inside that object you don't have standard name-value pairs. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified on the [Creating an app](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) page, the example code uses ECMAScript 2015 features. The specific feature you mention is enhanced object literal syntax, which is described [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).

Comment: You are right, but one thing is still inconsistent. On examples you mentioned (https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) they don't use single quotes with function name.